# What's going wrong in my template file?

Tags: 7, views, theming

I'm displaying a user's [messages](https://drupal.org/project/message) in a view (which contains the messages' mid) and created a [flag](https://drupal.org/project/flag) 'Unread' for them. (New messages are automatically flagged with a rule.) I'd now like to give the flagged ones a different background colour and tried editing the view's template file like this:

```
<?php if (!empty($title)): ?>
  <h3><?php print $title; ?></h3>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php foreach ($rows as $id => $row): ?>
  <?php $message = message_load($view->result[$id]->mid); ?>
  <?php $flag = flag_get_flag('unread'); ?>       
  <div <?php if ($classes_array[$id]) { print ' class="' . $classes_array[$id] .'"';  } ?>>
   <a class="inbox-message<?php if ($flag->is_flagged($message->mid)) {print " inbox-new";} ?>"
    <?php print $row; ?>
   </a>
  </div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

This works: flagged messages get the `inbox-new` class and I can theme them accordingly. Unfortunately, I'm also getting the error

```
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in include() (line 8 of C:\wamp\www\MYSITE\sites\all\themes\MYTHEME\templates\views-view-unformatted--message.tpl.php).
```

What did I do wrong?

---

**Edit:** I've executed

```
$message = message_load(9);
$flag = flag_get_flag('unread');
if ($flag->is_flagged($message->mid)) {print ", inbox-new";}
```

with Devel and that works perfectly. I can debug `$message` and `$flag` via the template and use it elsewhere without any problems, so the problem can't be caused by being undefined.

Comment: It means just that. The variable `$flag` set by `flag_get_flag('unread')` is not an object. So when you try to access `$flag->is_flagged`, PHP throws a notice. You should check to see if `$flag` is an object before trying to access it. (E.g. `if (is_object($flag)) { // do stuff }`)

Comment: can you post the view that you have created

Comment: It's not `$flag` causing the notice because you're not trying to get a property on it, you're calling a method. AFAICT that means it must be `$message` that isn't an object (perhaps it's NULL?). It might be worth doing a check on the return value from `message_load()`.

Comment: @AdamBalsam: Your suggestion didn't change the situation: the error messages were still there. I tried `is_object($message)` afterwards and that solved the problem. No idea why. Maybe a bug in the Message module?

Comment: @wolverine: The view is the standard 'Message' view, provided by the Message module. I only added a field with the messages' mid.

Comment: @Andy: It seems that we had the same idea at the same time. You are correct: `$message` causes the problem. I applied Adam Balsam's suggestion and that works (see my answer underneath). No idea why that was necessary, though...

Comment: If you wanted to investigate further, you could add `if (!is_object($message)) dpm($view->result[$id]->mid, 'mid');` below the line with `message_load()` and examine the MIDs displayed.

Comment: @Andy: Thanks for your debugging line. Didn't think about trying something like that. Oddly enough, there's always one flagged message that returns two identical errors. I can't find a pattern in it, however.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've changed line 8 to

```
<a class="inbox-message<?php if (is_object($message)) {if ($flag->is_flagged($message->mid)) {print " inbox-new";}} ?>"
```

and the error message vanishes magically. I've got no idea what caused this problem and why I had to solve it in this ugly way, so edits or comments with an explanation for this are welcome. Perhaps this is a bug in the Message module and I should report it on the drupal.org website.